# Терминал не подсвечивает vue

Tags: node.js, vue.js

Скачал для виндовс программу git bash
После установки nodejs и vue/cli терминал все отображает белым, стрелки не опускаются, что нужно сделать чтобы терминал интерактивно работал, а то не понятно где я нахожусь

Comment: А почему должно? Это прога для контроля версий, а не консоль для всего...

Comment: @VladimirGonchar это интерпретатор баш, встроенный в прогу контроля версий

Comment: @VladimirGonchar со встроенным cmd не удобно работать, вот я и скачал гит баш он больше похож на линуксовский терминал, просто не реагирует на стрелку вниз и вверхи не могу переключиться между менюшками который предостовляет vue

Comment: @eri линуксе в терминале переключается между менюшками, а виндовсе горит белым как будто завис, не получается сделать как на линуксе

Comment: терминал не тот выбрал при установке. переустанови

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При установке гит баш были опции в каком терминале работать, если выбрано было cmd - цвета не будет.

1. включи шрифты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Используй miniTTY

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! как обычно выручили